# setup for having an amp output mono to two speakers

Tags: stereo, speakers, amplifier, mono, setup

I have two passive bookshelf speakers [Micca - MB42X](http://www.miccatron.com/micca-mb42x/) and would like to use a single amp to send the same audio signal to each speaker.

I do not want one speaker to receive the **left** channel and one to receive the **right** channel; I want them both to receive mono.

How can I do this and what amp, splitters, wires, etc do I need?

Comment: Chris - as someone else commented, you should really have a look at a basic electronics primer if you want to understand this. It's not really on topic here, but won't take you long to learn.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be using a mixing console converting your signal to mono then routing back the signal to your amp.

In the same category, why don't you convert to mono your output source.
This kind of process is usually really simple with DAWs and depends on your OS but you should find options or programs that help you doing this kind of things

Another one would be to merge your stereo cables together then split them back into two **equal** cables. This type of practice may need the use of resistors for a better result (don't ask me why)
[Here is a really good electronic website](http://www.sonelec-musique.com/) (it's a french one so use a translator :) )

```
Left  ________                   _________ Output as two mono signals
              \     Merge       /
               -----------------
Right ________/                 \_________
```

Best,

Comment: If I convert the stereo signal to mono and then send that to the amp, is it possible that the amp might 're-split' the signal into stereo, such that the left and right channels that are output will be different?

Chromecast Audio 3.5mm --> convert stereo to mono --> Amp (outputs left and right channels, but each channel is the same) --> send one channel to each speaker

What if I convert the signal from stereo to mono after the amp outputs stereo, instead?

Chromecast Audio 3.5mm --> Amp (outputs stereo) --> convert stereo to mono --> duplicate the mono and send one channel to each speaker

Comment: @ChrisMorris In answer to your question, no. You can't convert mono to stereo, so the mixer won't do that. Converting to dual mono *before* the amp is much easier and safer than trying to do it between the amp and speakers.